# Possible to integrate github probot with splunk?

Tags: github, splunk, github-app

Building my first git app and ... But i'm thinking of a github app that could post to splunk ... or integrate with the splunk github app and "POST" events to the system; wondering if this functionality is/ can be supported somehow;

The real question is - can I send selective information about the repository from a git app to splunk ?

Possible ?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [GitHub Addon](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3739/) on Splunkbase that can be used to integrate with GitHub.com or an onprem instance.

Alternatively, you can look at using [Splunk HTTP Event Collector](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.0/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector) to receive formatted webhook calls and ingest data that way.

Comment: Thanks Simon! Looks like the HTTP Event collector is the way to go as well, curious if this has been done before ? Or how probot/github would recommend managing secrets ... specially if the app ends being being installed on an on-prem instance of git/splunk